Which file formats in Autodesk Viewer require a list of URNs for viewing?
I am working with the Autodesk Viewer API and need to better understand how to handle different file formats when it comes to viewing. I know that some formats, such as IFC, require a list of URNs to view multiple elements within a single file, while others, such as DWG, generally accept a single URN.
I am looking for information on which other formats supported by Autodesk Viewer require multiple URNs (i.e. a list) to display all content in a single view. This is especially true for formats that can contain multiple parts or layers, such as OBJ, FBX, and DWF, but I would like to know more details about the behavior of formats such as:
3DM, 3DS, CATPART, DAE, DWG, DXF, FBX, IFC, IGES, NWD, OBJ, RVT, SKP, STL, STEP
The API documentation is not very clear on when to use a list of URNs or a single URN. Could someone clarify how Autodesk Viewer handles these different formats or share a more detailed reference?
I've looked through the Autodesk Viewer API documentation and done some testing with different formats, such as DWG and IFC. I've noticed that when viewing IFC files, Autodesk Viewer requires a list of URNs to display all the elements, while for DWG this doesn't seem to be necessary. I've tried to find a complete list of formats and the viewing requirements for each, but I haven't found a clear explanation in the documentation.

Before using APS Viewer to view the file formats you mentioned, you must translate the file using Model Derivative API to the viewer support formats - SVF/SVF2, which are Autodesk's proprietary file formats for APS viewer SDK.
The URN is the encoded object key of the file you uploaded to APS OSS bucket based on AWS S3. APS Viewer needs the URN to know where your translated results (SVF/SVF2) are. One URN stands for one file (e.g. An IFC file)
Here are the tutorials for your reference:

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/task3-translate-source-file/
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-roominfo4viewer/task3-translate-source-file/

In addition, I would advise you to follow this step-by-step tutorial to learn how to play with APS API and APS Viewer SDK: https://get-started.aps.autodesk.com/tutorials/simple-viewer/

Hi Eason, I noticed that some views or comparisons fail and do not show a detailed log. For example, I have some comparisons that return the error "Compare job failed: failedInstructions". I couldn't find anything in the documentation related to these errors, just general hints that the file could be corrupted or contain an xref, which is not my case. Could you help me with this?

Hi Fabio, sorry, I cannot comment with limited info. Please share the manifest and urn with us via the "Contact support" of https://aps.autodesk.com/get-help
